# Accessing Python Database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to create a website where people can check their grades along with information about my school (I ultimately want to make an iOS app, but need a Mac).  Making the website should be easy, but our school does not have any form of API for getting the grades.  However, I found a guy who made an unofficial API for our district for an iOS app.

I have tried to find information about using the API, which runs on Python, with JavaScript, but I can not find anything that works. I know close to nothing about Python, and I would like to see if someone could help me set this up.

The API is by the user sshh12 on GitHub, and the link to it is [here](https://github.com/sshh12/CFISD-API).

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help me do this.

Comment: Looks like you need an XmlHttpRequest for that. There a few library that saves you from using the Vanilla Javascript way. Jquery is the most common, but it's quite heavy.

Comment: request library or subprocess using curl